# Azure Data Factory with .NET Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

In Azure, I have an Azure Function which uses .NET and is defined as follows

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
String accessToken = XXXXXXXXXX;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", accessToken);
var result = await client.GetAsync("https://allstate.myabsorb.com/api/rest/v1/Coupons");
string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
log.LogInformation(resultContent);
}
return (ActionResult) new OkResult();
}
```

I originally ran this as a stand-alone function and it runs successfully. The `XXXXX` in the code above represents an authorization token, which runs successfully if I hard-code this token into the code. However, as the token changes, I created a step in Azure Data Factory that retrieves the updated token and stores it in a variable. **I want to take that ADF variable and pass it into the function.** What do I need to do in the code in order for the function to be able to interpret this ADF variable when the function gets executed?

All I'm trying to pass into the function is a single string. I just have no idea how to do this and can't find any examples that are simplistic enough for my smooth ape brain to comprehend. I feel like this is should be a fairly simple process, but I just can't figure it out...
What do?

EDIT: to clarify, my main problem here is I don't know what to put in the *code* for it to receive the variable from ADF.

Comment: You can pass as Header to HttpReqeust which is being initiated from ADF. And in your function you can check the header in `req` object.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp). The `XXXX` simply needs to be replaced with `req.Query["name"]` where "name" is the name of the variable in the Azure Data Factory pipeline "Set variable" activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the token in the header or body.

For example, if you put the token in the body, then you can get the token in your http trigger like this:

`req.Body`

And on the side of ADF. You can use dynamic content to get the variable:

[image]

Click the blank space:

[image]

Set variable activity(you can set dynamic value here from some other places.):

[image]

function app activity:

[image]

This is the official doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables

Comment: Okay but what do I do with the hard-coded string in my code? Do I just remove it? I didn't write this code. I just found it online so I don't really understand how it can receive the header...